# Array event listener for drag n drop image in js

Tags: javascript, html

based on this [tutorial](https://cube3x.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-image-preview-using-html5/) i modified the code from id selector to class for multiple file uploads, no js error, no break, but the code seems not working now

is there's anything wrong with the code ?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u16phphj/)

Thanks

```
<div class="filedroparea">DROP IMAGE HERE</div>
<img class="previewimage" alt="Preview Image"/>
<div class="showdroparea">Drop New Image</div>
<div class="filedroparea">DROP IMAGE HERE</div>
<img class="previewimage" alt="Preview Image"/>
<div class="showdroparea">Drop New Image</div>
<div class="filedroparea">DROP IMAGE HERE</div>
<img class="previewimage" alt="Preview Image"/>
<div class="showdroparea">Drop New Image</div>

if (window.FileReader) {
    // Current browser supports drag and drop

    var droparea = document.getElementsByClassName("filedroparea");
    for(var i=0; i< droparea.length; i++){
        droparea[i].addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
        droparea[i].addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
        droparea[i].addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
    }

    var showButton = document.getElementsByClassName("showdroparea");
    for(var i=0; i< showButton.length; i++){
     showButton[i].addEventListener("click", showarea, false);
    }
} 

else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('filedroparea').innerHTML = 'Your browser does not support FileReader HTML5 API';
}

// Event callback functions
function dragenter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get list of dropped files
    var dt = e.dataTransfer;
    var images = dt.files;
    //console.log(images);

    // Reading first file
    var image = images[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    for(var i=0; i< reader.length; i++){
    reader[i].readAsDataURL(image);

    reader[i].addEventListener("loadend", showPreview, false);
}
}

function showPreview(e, file){
    var imageElement = document.getElementsByClassName('previewimage');
        for(var i=0; i< imageElement.length; i++){
        imageElement[i].src = this.result;

    document.getElementsByClassName("filedroparea").style.display = 'none';
    imageElement[i].style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementsByClassName("showdroparea").style.display = 'block';
}

}

function showarea(e){
    document.getElementsByClassName("filedroparea").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementsByClassName('previewimage').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName("showdroparea").style.display = 'none';
}

html,body{margin:0, padding:0; text-align:center; background: #eee url('../images/bg.png'); font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px;}

a{font-size: 12px; color: #666;}

.filedroparea{margin: 50px auto; width: 600px; height: 300px; border: 5px dashed #FF0066; text-align:center; line-height: 300px;text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;}

.previewimage{display:none; margin:50px auto; max-width:600px; box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #aaa;}

.showdroparea{display:none; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; padding: 8px 0px; color: #fff; background: #5A8AFA; width: 150px; margin: auto; text-transform: uppercase; border-bottom: 2px solid #4A77E0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The original tutorial uses document.getElementById() which returns a DOM node.

document.getElementsByClassName() returns an array of multiple DOM nodes.  After switching to getElementsByClassName() you will need to loop through the Array and set the new style attribute on each element individually. Try this:

```
function hideAll(elements) {
  var length = elements.length;
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function showAll(elements) {
  var length = elements.length;
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function showarea(e){
    var filedropareas = document.getElementsByClassName("filedroparea");
    var previewimages = document.getElementsByClassName('previewimage');
    var showdropareas = document.getElementsByClassName("showdroparea");
    showAll(filedropareas);
    hideAll(previewimages);
    hideAll(showdropareas);
}
```